# Retrieve data on click in v-for loop and then loop through the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I have a button in a v-for loop that when clicked retrieves some data. I then want to display that data below or in place of the button that was clicked.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <button @click="fetchData(item.id)">Load Data</button>
  <ul v-if="THEDATALOADED">
    <li v-for="(data, index) in THEDATALOADED">
      {{ data.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also want to retain all the data below each button that was clicked, so I can't just set this.THEDATALOADED = response.data, if I did, it would display that data in all the v-for iterations and update them all as well when any button is clicked.

Comment: I think that's a cool idea. If only one could use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you push the fetched data in the correspondant item :

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <button @click="fetchData(item.id,index)">Load Data</button>
  <ul v-if="item.THEDATALOADED">
    <li v-for="(data, index) in item.THEDATALOADED">
      {{ data.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

in the `fetchData` method :

```
 fetchData(id,index){
      ....
      let tmp=this.items[index];
      tmp.THEDATALOADED=response.data;
      this.$set(this.items,index,tmp);
      ...
  }
```

The following running code illustrates your use case, in this example i have a set of users, and each user has some posts that he created, when i click on the `load Posts` button it will fetch the posts of the correspondant user :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [],
  },
  mounted() {

    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => {
        this.users = response.data
      })
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts(id, index) {
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + id)
        .then((response) => {
          let tmp = this.users[index];
          tmp.posts = response.data;
          this.$set(this.users, index, tmp);
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-axios@2.1.4/dist/vue-axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
      <span>{{user.name}}</span>
      <button @click="getPosts(user.id,index)">load Posts</button>
      <ul v-if="user.posts">
        <li v-for="(post, index) in user.posts">
          {{ post.title}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```